# jQuery to toggle show/hide multiple divs and change text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I've been searching and trying snippets for days without any success. I really know next to nothing about Javascript and while I can get close, I simply can't achieve what I'm after. I need to have a link/button that when clicked will toggle visibility of the div below and also change the text from + to - (or show to hide). I have the display toggling working but I can't get the text to change at the same time. Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleDiv(divId) {
   jQuery("#"+divId).toggle();
}
</script>

<a href="javascript:toggleDiv('hidden1');" class="button" >+</a> Day 1
<div id="hidden1" style="display:none;">
Day 1 Details
</div>

<a href="javascript:toggleDiv('hidden2');" class="button">+</a> Day 2
<div id="hidden2" style="display:none;">
Day 2 Details
</div>
```

Note: I'm doing this on a wordpress site if that makes a difference (I believe I can't use $). I only want this loading on specific pages though which is why I'm attempting it myself instead of using a plugin. And I have two divs in the above example but I will actually have around 30 so don't want to specify exact ID's. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do something like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.button').click(function(){
   id = $(this).attr('title');
   txt = $(this).text();
   if (txt == '+'){
     $(this).text('-');
   }
   else{
      $(this).text('+');
   }
   $("#"+id).toggle();

  })

});
```

HTML

```
<a class="button" title="hidden1" >+</a> Day 1
<div id="hidden1" style="display:none;">
Day 1 Details
</div>

<a class="button" title="hidden2">+</a> Day 2
<div id="hidden2" style="display:none;">
Day 2 Details
</div>
```

Checkout this [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/vuniqu/1/)

Comment: Ahh you're amazing! I had to change $ to jQuery but this works perfectly. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

No sweat.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleDiv(divId) {
   var div=jQuery("#"+divId),
   t=div.prev().children().first();
   div.toggle();
   t.text(t.text()=="+"?"-":"+");
}
</script>

<a href="javascript:toggleDiv('hidden1');" class="button" >+</a> Day 1
<div id="hidden1" style="display:none;">
Day 1 Details
</div>

<a href="javascript:toggleDiv('hidden2');" class="button">+</a> Day 2
<div id="hidden2" style="display:none;">
Day 2 Details
</div>
```

Alternatively, if you don't want a hassle at all, try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.button').each(function(){
        var t=jQuery(this);
        t.parent().next().toggle();
        t.text(t.text()=="+"?"-":"+");
    });
});
</script>

<a href="javascript:void()" class="button" >+</a> Day 1
<div id="hidden1" style="display:none;">
Day 1 Details
</div>

<a href="javascript:void()" class="button">+</a> Day 2
<div id="hidden2" style="display:none;">
Day 2 Details
</div>
```

Also, if you want to be a bad boy, you can always just begin your script with `window.$=jQuery;` and then you can actually use `$` in your code.

Comment: I can't quite get this to work. The first example seems to change the entire link and text 'Day 1' to the '-' text and then it is no longer clickable. I have this example at http://www.libertadtravel.com/tours/small-taste-of-ca/ for viewing.

Comment: Ah, yes, the problem is that Wordpress puts everything in <p> elements.  The second example also likely won't work, because the input HTML isn't actually the output HTML.  Let me revise the code.